# Avoiding reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have 81 classes(still growing) which implement  an interface, and I have a class that has a property that represents that interface ex:

```
public wrapper
{
   public Imyinterface instance{get;set;}

   public wrapper(string theNameOfTheClass)
   {
    instance = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(theNameOfTheClass);
    instance.Run(); //the interface has a run method
   }
}
```

is this the best way to go with, and how can I  avoid reflection and not have to write any extra code?

Comment: What is the goal of `wrapper`? Why would I call `new Wrapper("Imp12").Instance` over `new Imp12()`?

Comment: the wrapper has the methods that are shared between the classes, they produce the same data format and the wrapper basicly does some processing after the Run() method is done

Comment: Why not just make the classes implement a common interface?

Comment: @MichalCiechan they already do as i mentioned

Comment: then why don't you just do `var a = new SomeClass(); a.Run();`?

Comment: Just saw your comment above, why not have an abstract class, which does the processing after run, and in your child classes, ensure you call base.Run();?

Comment: @MichalCiechan because an instance of a wrapper is created based on what a user selects from a listbox, no hard coding is involved

Comment: @user1492051 what about IoC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Unity IoC (or any other IoC that can resolve from string):

From [IOC Container Runtime Resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718175/ioc-container-runtime-resolution)

```
string typeName = "MyTypeName";
var type = container.Registrations.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RegisteredType.Name == typeName);
if(type != null)
{
    var resolvedInstance = container.Resolve(type.RegisteredType);
}
```

EDIT: For Convention over Configuration have a look at the links at links in this question

[Using Unity With Minimal Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520518/using-unity-with-minimal-configuration)

Comment: Ok, but you have to register these classes somewhere before using that, don't you?

Comment: Yes, but you can do convention over configuration. E.g. give it a namespace and/or assembly to look in, and it will register all classes from there.

Comment: I know, where you're going, but this solution will effectively only delegate usage of the reflection to another class, won't it? :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, but maybe:

```
public Wrapper<T>
   where T : IMyInterface, new()
{
    public IMyInstance instance { get; set; }

    public Wrapper()
    {
        instance = new T();
        instance.Run();
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
Wrapper<SomeClass> wrapper = new Wrapper<SomeClass>();
```

If you want to keep the wrappers on some kind of list, simply derive them from common, non-generic class:

```
public abstract class BaseWrapper
{

}

public class Wrapper<T> : BaseWrapper
...
```

---

**Edit:** In response to comments

Maybe the problem is not in the wrapper class. If you get a string from user, you have only two options: either a giant switch or reflection.

You may change that for example by changing the ListBox contents:

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Func<IMyInterface> creator { get; set; }        

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
}
```

Now create a list of these items and pass it to the ComboBox:

```
var items = new[] {
    new ComboBoxItem { Title = "First class", creator = () => new FirstClass() },
    new ComboBoxItem { Title = "Second class", creator = () => new SecondClass() },
}
```

You have to populate that ComboBox anyway, so there *will* be some hardcoding. The point is to hardcode the class list only in one place (maybe even in a place unrelated to the ComboBox, and then re-create ComboBox contents basing on that list).

Comment: but problem is i don't want to hard code, because there are too many classes, and and a wrapper instance is created based on the selected value from a listbox and it recives a string of the class name

Comment: populating the combobox is not a problem since the data is available in an sql database that is filled by a blond secretary ;)

Comment: If you have no way of matching strings with class types in the code, I guess you're out of options and you'll have to use reflection one way or another. You may do it a little bit nicer, as @MichalCiechan suggests.